# Scope of static inner class in java

Tags: java, static-methods, inner-classes

I found a very strange thing today. I have the following class with a static inner class.

```
public class PDto {

private Agreement agreement = new Agreement();

    public static class Agreement{
        public String agreementName;
        public String agreementDescription;
        public String currency;
    }

    public Agreement getAgreement() {
        return agreement;
    }

    public void setAgreement(Agreement agreement) {
        this.agreement = agreement;
    }
}
```

Another class ClassA which has the following method :-

```
private Agreement createBillingAgreement(PDto payment) {

    PDto.Agreement billingAgreement = payment.getAgreement();
    Agreement agreement = new Agreement();
    agreement.setName(billingAgreement.agreementName);
    agreement.setDescription(billingAgreement.agreementDescription);
    billingAgreement.agreementName = "Changed agreeement Name" ;
}
```

Class B's code which calls method of Class A

```
classBService.createBillingAgreement(payment);
System.out.println("Changed billing agreement name : " + payment.getAgreement().agreementName);
```

And when I print the agreement name from class ClassB, I get the value which was set in `createBillingAgreement` method of class A. How is that possible.

Comment: Please post all the relevant code. The code you posted doesn't even pass compilation.

Comment: Your question isn't completely clear to me but `payment.getAgreement()` would return the `agreement` instance in `PDto` (and `billingAgreement.agreementName  = "Changed agreeement Name" ` sets that instance's name) while `Agreement agreement = new Agreement();` creates an independent instance - but what is done with it isn't entirely clear since the return statement of `createBillingAgreement(...)` is missing (and maybe other parts as well).

Comment: Just a side note to prevent any potential misconception: static inner classes don't have any special relationship with their outer classes. The outer class only acts as a form of namespace but that's it.

Comment: you pass `payment` to `createBillingAgreement`, updating name inside method and print it out. What name you expecting to print it out, and why? Because from that what you describe, everything works like it should.

Comment: I thought that the scope of `payment` and `agreement` object is only inside `createBillingAgreement`. And when I print `billingAgreement.agreementName` from another class, it should not print `"Changed agreeement Name"`.

Comment: @viper in java when you are passing object to method, you are not working with copy of object, but with object itself. Hence if you update field, this field will be updated outside of method. Unless you pass immutable copy of object, but that's different story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static-inner class is used to access at the same class statically. For example:

```
public class Parent{
    public static class Child{
        public void aMethod(String s){
            System.out.println("Hi!" + s);
        }
    }
}

public class AnotherClass{
    public void AnotherMethod(){
        Parent.Child.aMethod("From AnotherClass");
    }
}
```

OUT:

Hi! From AnotherClass

Or in your case:

```
PTdo.Agreement

        ^
```

this is the static class